# Container view positioning issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I've got a strange positioning issue that I can't figure out.

I have a container view inside a scroll view. I set constraints for the container; leading space and top space 0 to the superview (scrollview), AND I have code that tries to set the container to be flush with the top. Neither works, even though the container's origin y value is showing up as 0 (see the log). What's going on?

I am trying to get the container view (purple bg) flush with the top of the scroll view (red bg).

[image: I am trying to get the container view (purple bg) flush with the top of the scroll view (red bg)]

Comment: Probably unrelated, but you should call `[super viewWillLayoutSubviews]` when the method is overridden

Comment: Thank you, Jugale.
I figured out how to get what I wanted: move the upper bounds of the scrollview to the top of the layout (above where it says "Index"). It seems like Xcode is moving things down automatically because the view is in a navigation controller.